# Changing(Overriding) The Text of Multiple Paragraph Element's Through DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**I am Using "Query-Method" But it is not changing any paragraph content , this method works fine for
Single Element  overiding text. But not for Multiple Elements**

```
<body>
<!--HTML-->
<h1>Changing Text of Multiple Elemenet's via DOM</h1>
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<!-- JS -->
<script>
  let box = document.querySelector(".box");
  let paraChange = box.querySelectorAll('p').innerText = "Modified";  // This approch is not working!
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `box.querySelectorAll('p')` doesn't return one DOM node. So `.innerText` won't work

Comment: Have a read of the question I've linked?

Comment: I read it.Will the For loop work for it?

Comment: yes a loop will help you here. that is what the linked question says